# TinyMCE SetContent removing base64 content of second image

Tags: javascript, image, base64, tinymce

I have 2 TinyMCE editors. I want to write and paste images to the first editor, and have it appear in the second editor. It works without a problem if I only paste one image. I can paste the same image multiple times, and it keeps on appearing in the second editor.

However, once I paste a second, different image, the second image won't show. Although the content looks good before I execute `setContent()`, the result is not as expected. The content of the target TinyMCE editor does not include the base64 image info and the  `<img ...>` tag is replaced by  `<img />`, see image below:

[image]

[Here you can find a JsFiddle with some example code.](https://jsfiddle.net/malla/g8fxam43/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. 
I changed this:

```
      var descr = vm.getActualContent(tinymce.get('fromArea').getContent());
```

... to this:

```
      var descr = vm.getActualContent(tinymce.get('fromArea').getContent({ format: 'raw' }));
```